# Get html from view and get style for each child view?

Tags: html, react-native, jsx

I am trying to get child views to be converted to HTML string exactly the same with styles, after exploring React class I saw:

`React.createElement()`

which returns:

`DetailedReactHTMLElement<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>`

So is there any way to get the HTML as string?

Comment: Have you tried `toString()`

Comment: Yes already tried that, printed child.toString() after looping using:
`React.Children.forEach(view.props.children, function(child){console.log(child.toString()) })` but I get "[object Object]"

Comment: You should use this then https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html

Comment: After adding react-dom package its throwing error: "Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined" the error is thrown by react-dom-server.node.development.js (2748:112) I think it's not compatible with React-Native

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you using react-native, since react native does not have DOM elements only native. You can try find other packages, but if you prefer with just react native then I am not sure, sorry.